# How to generate lognormal distributed random variable using c++ boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to generate different random numbers following different distributions to conduct some experiments on them. I choose the boost library in c++ because I saw a large number of functions build in there. For example, in lognormal distribution, I followed this page https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/lognormal_dist.html and some more. But I cannot understand how I can actually generate the random number. I tried
`int main(){boost::math::lognormal_distribution<> myLognormal{0,8};cout << myLognormal() << endl;    return 0;}`
but its doing nothing but error.

Comment: You need a random engine.

Comment: [std::lognormal_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/lognormal_distribution) has example usage.

Comment: @Jarod42 random engine means. How can I use this in code. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You don't really need boost for this. Standard C++11 has plenty of distributions and examples, like the one that Jarod42 linked. If you still want to use something from boost, the latest documentation on their distributions library is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/math/doc/html/dist.html . Check under "Worked examples" for some sample programs.

Comment: OK @Jarod42 The problem is done with std::lognormal but sustains with boost::math::loghnormal. Because when I pass the generator to boost::math::lognormal it does not work.

Comment: You probably want to look at [boost_random](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_random.html). your distribution from `boost::math` seems not be used to generate numbers, but working with distribution properties.

Answer (score 1):

You have had some helpful comments already. Let me tie it together into an example:

### Using Standard Library (C++11 and up)

**Live On Coliru**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 engine; // uniform random bit engine

    // seed the URBG
    std::random_device dev{};
    engine.seed(dev());

    // setup a distribution:
    double mu    = 1.0;
    double sigma = 1.0;
    std::lognormal_distribution<double> dist(mu, sigma);

    for (int i = 1'000; i--;) {
        std::cout << dist(engine) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Plotting those numbers:

[https://plotly.com/~sehe/27/](https://plotly.com/%7Esehe/27/)

[image]

### Using Boost Random

Same with Boost Random:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c836d5ec5a022ad)**

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::random::mt19937 engine; // uniform random bit engine

    // seed the URBG
    boost::random::random_device dev;
    engine.seed(dev); // actually without call operator is better with boost

    // setup a distribution:
    double mu    = 1.0;
    double sigma = 1.0;
    boost::random::lognormal_distribution<double> dist(mu, sigma);

    for (int i = 1'000; i--;) {
        std::cout << dist(engine) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note that you need to link the Boost Random library then.